# how to redirect to home page after submitting redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have created a redux form, which when clicked on submit button doesn't redirect to the app.js page the url changes to this `http://localhost:3000/?name=Cook&phone=45625465265&email=cook%40yahoo&work=Engineer&city=`

this is what i have written-

form.js

```
const Form=({handleSubmit})=>(
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <center>
    <div>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Address</label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </center>
  </form>
)


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'form',
  fields: ['name', 'address']
})(Form);
```

add.js

```
class AddNew extends Component{
  handleSubmit = (values) => {
      console.log('This Values',values)
  }
  render() {


    return (
    <div style={{ padding: 150 }}>
      <Add onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
    </div>
  )}
  }
```

Comment: can you show the code, as to how you are calling the Redux form and then how are you trying to redirect

Comment: @Shubham i have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to `Redirect`, what you can do is that in the `handleSubmit` function of `AddNew` component, you can call dynamic routing with `this.props.history.push()`

Now supposing your `App.js` is specified in the Routes with path `/app`

You can do the following

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

class AddNew extends Component{

  handleSubmit = (values) => {
      console.log('This Values',values)
      this.props.history.push('/app');
  }
  render() {


    return (
    <div style={{ padding: 150 }}>
      <Add onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
    </div>
  )}
  }

export default withRouter(AddNew);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shubham. Can you tel me how can i pass these values in app and how can i print this in consoleof app.js?

Comment: i am not able to access props.formStates at app.js :(

Comment: Can you add your app component code in the previous question that you asked

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you have a failed request for whatever reason, you probably don't want to redirect...

Comment: @Will, In that case you would conditionally write `this.props.history.push('/app');` when the request is a success